# custom route caught by REST update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Hotel resource in my Rails app. I added a few custom, non-RESTful actions for some additional functionality.

I have the following routes.rb file:

```
resources :hotels do
  post 'sort', on: :collection
  post 'update_hotel_settings', on: :collection
end
```

and  here is the output from `rake routes`:

```
....
              sort_hotels POST   /hotels/sort(.:format)                                     hotels#sort
    update_hotel_settings POST   /hotels/update_hotel_settings(.:format)                    hotels#update_hotel_settings
                   hotels GET    /hotels(.:format)                                          hotels#index
                          POST   /hotels(.:format)                                          hotels#create
                new_hotel GET    /hotels/new(.:format)                                      hotels#new
               edit_hotel GET    /hotels/:id/edit(.:format)                                 hotels#edit
                    hotel GET    /hotels/:id(.:format)                                      hotels#show
                          PUT    /hotels/:id(.:format)                                      hotels#update
                          DELETE /hotels/:id(.:format)                                      hotels#destroy
```

The update_hotel_settings action is where some general settings are saved to the DB. 
Here is the beggining of the form being sent to that action:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@store, url: update_hotel_settings_hotels_path, html: {class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'hotel-settings-form'}) do |f| %>
```

giving:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/hotels/update_hotel_settings" class="simple_form form-horizontal" id="hotel-settings-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">...
```

However after submitting the form, the POST request is caught by the hotels' REST update action, with an exception about net being able to find hotel with id="update_hotel_settings".

Obviously this is an unwanted result, and I can't seem to find it's cause.
Shouldn't the update action be triggered by PUT/PATCH methods, and not POST? I also tried using another name for the route+action, instead of "update_hotel_settings", with no luck.

What's most annoying is that the sort action, listed right above, works fine! (only difference is the 'sort' action is fired via ajax, but not sure that should matter)

**EDIT:**

Contrary to what you might think, nested route mappers actually take precedent over the resource's 7 default routes.

**EDIT 2: Another Clue, Another Question!**

At first I was embarrassed to notice I forgot the `method: :post` option in the simple_form_for's arguments, and when I added it - Kapow! the form routes to the right action! weird isn't it? especially when there was already a method="post" attribute in the form tag!

WHAT IS GOING ON?

Comment: Contrary to what you may say, your `rake routes` shows you the actual route order...

Comment: My bad then, I was editting it a bit, didn't realize the order was significant. The unedited output is now posted

Answer (score -1):

Routes are caught top to bottom. Meaning, if there is a match, there it stops. So, all you have to do is take the update_hotel_settings route out of the resource and before it.

```
match '/hotels/update_hotel_settings', to: 'hotels#update_hotel_settings', via: 'post', as :update_hotel_settings_hotels
resources :hotels do
    [...]
```